# How to remove escape character in JSON files Azure Data Flow

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I have a cosmos db mongo db collection as source. I am supposed to provide a json.gz file as output. I've also been given a partition count, which states the number of partitions the output file should be. I'm first staging the file with .json extension with the help of copy activity and then using this stage file as source and then load it to a .json.gz file and i've selected set partitioning round robin in sink optimize tab to partition, this happens in azure data flows as it's the only one which has partitioning.

The output file i'm getting doesn't seem to be compressing and few strings have `'\'` escape character in them, I do not want them.

The output is like this:

`"id":"123","businesses":"[{\"titleAtBusiness\":\"MANAGER\"}]`

I want it like this:

`"id":"123","businesses":"[{"titleAtBusiness":"MANAGER"}]`

I want the `"\"` gone.

Stage JSON Sink Settings:
[image]

[image]

Json GZ Sink Settings:
[image]

[image]

[image]

Data FLow:
[image]

Comment: There is no difference in the current output and expected output. Could you check again?

Comment: Can you share the image of copy activity settings.(sink tab)

Comment: Updated screenshots of stage sink and json gz sink, i'm staging because i've been given rows per partition count, so from stage i'd get the count and write a logic to determine the number of partitions

Comment: Cosmos to JSON Stage ADLS - Copy Activity
 and 
Stage to json.gz ADLS - Azure Data Flow

Comment: in Staging blob, are you seeing data with escape character`\`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256094/discussion-between-aswin-and-prem-raj).